# Can I pass a multiline argument to rake task? (Not using ENV vars)

Tags: rake, rake-task

Both

```
rake some:task["aaa
bbb
ccc"]
```

and

```
rake some:task["aaa\nbbb\nccc"]
```

fail.

Dose Rake accept multiline arguments in the first place?

Comment: I know how to pass multiple args to Rake. What I want to know is how to pass a multi-LINE parameter to Rake.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
require 'rake'

task :taskname, [:argument1, :argument2] do |t, args|
  puts "Args are: #{args}"
end
```

In command line:

```
> rake taskname[1,2]
Args are: {:argument1=>"1", :argument2=>"2"}
```

Comment: Yes, then how can I multiline strings to for example argument2?

`rake taskname[1,"a\nb"]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the code and found that it's impossible to send multi "line" params to rake command.

https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/86af0ef6d793b85068a44fb3407b23c9c9b09bc7/lib/rake/application.rb#L154

> /^some_patterns$/ =~ string.to_s

It looks like a rake command is supposed to be a single line.